# My for loop won't repeat the correct conditions

Tags: python

Is there anything wrong with my code? It should run about 500 times. But after it appends once it won't append again until the next elif condition is met.

```
for x in range(lengthOfListedContent):

    if listed_content[x][0] is books[0]:
        notes[0].append(listed_content[x][2])
        print(x)
    elif listed_content[x][0] is books[1]:
        notes[1].append(listed_content[x][2])
        print(x)
    elif listed_content[x][0] is books[2]:
        notes[2].append(listed_content[x][2])
        print(x)
    elif listed_content[x][0] is books[3]:
        notes[3].append(listed_content[x][2])
        print(x)
    else:
       print('fail')
```

This is the output I get:

```
0
1
fail
fail
5
fail
fail
fail
9
fail
fail
```

It should append at every iteration but it only appends at the first iteration of the met condition. I have no idea why it just skips until the next elif condition is met. I've been staring at the screen for hours.

Sorry if all this is convoluted, I'm still new..

Comment: `is` and `==` is two different things. are you sure you want `is`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `is` instead of `==`?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing whats in `listed_content` and `books`, but you should try replacing `is` with `==` unless you have a very specific reason for using `is`.

Comment: It would be easier to help you knowing what is in the `listed_content` & `books` lists(?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using is between two arguments is comparing their ids instead of their values.

`is` tests for identity, not equality

Change all lines with `is` to `==`

From:

```
if listed_content[x][0] is books[0]:
```

To:

```
if listed_content[x][0] == books[0]:
```

Comment: you can also replace the loop with `for x in listed_content` to make everything a bit more Pythonic. Judging from the names,  `lengthOfListedContent` probably is `len(listed_content)`

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the reason. Wasted 2 hours over this lol.

Comment: There are many things that can be fixed, including running in three nested loops as there is a relation to notes, book and listed_content which all are lists.

Comment: @omri_saadon Yeah I realise that there are many best practices that I missed out. I would like to make it work before I start trimming the fat.